# Does RenderTransformOrigin influence scale transforms?

Tags: wpf, transform, inkcanvas

I am trying to do scale transforms on an InkCanvas and some unseen force seems to be influencing how the scale works. When I try to set CenterX and CenterY they appear to be being ignored.

Update: I should note that the ink canvas is wrapped with a viewbox, I suppose that could be influencing it too...

Comment: I'd recommend trying to distill this down to a simple example and post the code. It's hard to tell what the issue could be just based on your description.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out and it does. E.g. in order to make a control sweep from right to left I moved the **RenderTransformOrigin** to **"1, 0"** .

I am not certain about the documentation but it could be that ***CenterX/Y*** relate not to normalized proportions but to the actual size of the UIElement. If that's the case it is sort of useless.